# A Word for a Society in which the Power Source is Your Contacts

Tags: single-word-requests

Does a word exist for a society or a tendency in which the power source is based on your contacts?

For example: Let us assume that I am applying for a job. I know Joe, the boss, and because of this, he hires me in front of other, more qualified applicants. Then we can say that I am living in a _________.

I am looking for a word similar to oligarchy, meritocracy, and so on.

I assume there is no such word, but I thought it was worth a try here anyway.

Comment: With a negative undertone, it's a nepotistic society or you can say it's ruled by cronyism or favouritism. On a more informal level you can also say  it's a "jobs for the boys" society . Look up these words in a dictionnary.

Comment: it's like chaibol culture in Korea...

Comment: and Guanxi in China.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from *cronyism*, you can extend it to:

> ***[Crony Capitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crony_capitalism)*** is a term describing an economy in which success in business depends on close relationships between business people and government officials.
>
> Crony capitalism is believed to arise when business cronyism and related self-serving behavior by businesses or businesspeople spills over into politics and government, or when self-serving friendships and family ties between businessmen and the government influence the economy and society to the extent that it corrupts public-serving economic and political ideals.

Comment: Thank you. I should have specified the post better, I was also looking for a word that could be used in a political sense as well. This is perfect!

Comment: just "cronyism" is a single word you can use. and there's the "old boys network" in a more BrE setting.

Answer (score 2):

***[Connection](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/connection)*** is the key word to refer to a  *non-meritocratic society*.

> - A person, especially one of influence or importance, with whom one is associated, as by kinship or common interests: *used her connections to land a job.* .(AHD)

- I am living in a world  where connections are more  important than meritocracy

[Cronyism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cronyism) , as suggested in a comment, is a useful term, but it is mainly used in political, public contexts:

> - (Government, Politics & Diplomacy) the practice of appointing friends to high-level, esp political, posts regardless of their suitability. (Collins)

Answer (score 1):

Collusion, or a secret or illegal cooperation or conspiracy, especially in order to cheat or deceive others, could fit the bill (ie "I am [operating] in a state of collusion."). I'd imagine your best bet will end up being a phrase rather than a single word.

Comment: Collusion is an interesting term, but I think it has much wider implications than those suggested in the question.